# Swift 2.2 error handling by try block

Tags: swift, try-catch, swift-playground, swift2

I've just started to learn Swift couple of days ago. In my Xcode playground I have the following code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

enum VendingMachineError: ErrorType {
    case InvalidSelection
    case InsufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: Int)
    case OutOfStock
}


func requestBeverage(code: Int, coins: Int) throws {
    guard code > 0 else  {
        throw VendingMachineError.InvalidSelection
    }
    if coins < 2 {
        throw VendingMachineError.InsufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: 3)
    }
    guard coins > 10 else {
        throw VendingMachineError.OutOfStock
    }

    print("everything went ok")
}



try requestBeverage(-1, coins: 4)
print("finished...")
```

If I try to run it, nothing happens. but I would expect to print "finished..." because in my logic, it tries to do something, fails, then the program would continue....

So the question is, why isn't the program continuing, and how can I tell the code to continue in case of error with as little words as possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is "everything went ok" printed?

Comment: Are you sure it's Swift 3? Swift 3, as far as I know, is not even in beta yet (it will be after WWDC 2016, and will probably be released somewhere around  September). It is Swift 2.2 most likely (the current version).

Comment: When did Apple released swift 3.0? Did I missed that release? Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: I see. I got the ++ deprecation error so I assumed it's 3.0. but I think you are right.

Comment: @OWADVL Deprecation means that something is planned to be removed in a future version (in this case Swift 3.0), but still works perfectly well in the current version (Swift 2.2). The compiler is just warning you that you should be making your code Swift 3.0 ready (so you don't have tons of sudden errors to deal with when it's released).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch all errors individually with `do`/`catch`:

```
do {
    try requestBeverage(-1, coins: 4)
} catch VendingMachineError.InvalidSelection {
    print("Invalid selection")
} catch VendingMachineError.OutOfStock {
    print("Out of stock")
} catch VendingMachineError.InsufficientFunds(let coinsNeeded) {
    print("You need \(coinsNeeded) more coins")
} catch {
    // an unknown error occured
}

print("finished...")
```

Alternatively, use `try?` if you only care about whether an error is thrown, but not which one:

```
func requestSomeBeverage() {
    guard (try? requestBeverage(-1, coins: 4)) != nil else {
        print("An error has occured")
        return
    }
}

requestSomeBeverage()
print("finished...")
```

If you're absolutely sure an error will not be thrown, and you want to cause an exception when it does, use `try!` (but in most cases, don't):

```
try! requestBeverage(-1, coins: 4)
print("finished...")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the error

```
... 

do {
  try requestBeverage(-1, coins: 4)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
print("finished...")
```

See [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) in the Swift Language Guide

Edit: you can write the whole expression in one line ;-)

```
do { try requestBeverage(-1, coins: 4) } catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: ok, but your solution has 6 lines of code. is there something in ...1-2 lines ?

Comment: Actually there are 4(!) more lines. What's wrong with it? Of course you can put the `do` and the `catch` clause into one line respectively, but this doesn't really accelerate the performance ;-)

Comment: @TimVermeulen yes, I guess this is the solution with try? ... but is it the normal way to do it? or you would write a do/catch...

Comment: `do`/`catch` is usually the way to go because it allows you to `catch` individual errors. If you only care about whether an error is thrown but not which one, then use `try?`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen if you want make an answer and I'll accept it.